# Simplification of pseudo inverse of skinny fat matrix in least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

In solving a least squares problem, I have a pseudo-inverse in the regular form $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ where $A = \left[\begin{array}{c} I \\ \sqrt{\lambda} B \end{array} \right]$. The solution claims that I should be able to reduce this to $(I + \lambda B^TB)^{-1}$, but perhaps my linear algebra is too rusty to see how this is done.

I've tried starting with the block matrix transpose identity $\left[ \begin{array}{c} M \\ N \end{array} \right]^T = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} M^T & N^T\end{array}\right]$ to reduce the $(A^TA)^{-1}$ term to $\left[ \begin{array}{c} I \\ \lambda B^T B \end{array} \right]^{-1}$, but I'm not sure if this is correct or where to proceed from here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(A^T A)^{-1} = (I + \lambda B^T B)^{-1}$?

Comment: That looks correct. Why? I just realized that we're multiplying the quantity on the right by $[y \  0]$ so the $A^T$ outside the parenthesis just becomes the identity matrix. EDIT: Nevermind, got it.

Comment: Since $A^T = \begin{bmatrix}I & \sqrt{\lambda}B^T\end{bmatrix}$, due to how [block matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) is defined, $A^T A = I \cdot I + \sqrt{\lambda} B^T \cdot \sqrt{\lambda} B = I + \lambda B^T B$.